# Oracle SQLPLUS: Monitor data copy progress

Tags: python-3.x, oracle10g, sqlplus

i have written a python program that helps copy over data from one Oracle DB to another. It uses threading to concurrently copy data over several threads.

def run_sqlplus(sqlplus_script):

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['sqlplus', conn],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(stdout,stderr) = p.communicate(sqlplus_script.encode('utf-8'))
stdout_lines = stdout.decode('utf-8').split("\n")

return stdout_lines
```

The list specifies the queries to be executed

LST=["select COUNT(1) FROM a WHERE BUSINESS_DATE='30-Sep-2020' AND RUN_ID=1 AND PROCESSING_LOCATION='PAC';",
"select COUNT(1) FROM b WHERE BUSINESS_DATE='30-Sep-2020' AND RUN_ID=1 AND PROCESSING_LOCATION='PAC';",
"COPY FROM schema/pass@DB APPEND TABLE1 using select * FROM TABLE1 WHERE BUSINESS_DATE='30-Sep-2020' ;"
]

I have mapped the List (LST) to the the below threadpool executor:

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_threads) as executor:

```
results=[executor.submit(execute_queries,i) for i in LST]

for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
    print(f.result())
```

While running the code it seems the copy commands are running longer than expected. Is there any way that i can monitor the progress of the threads in python or the SID/SERIAL# in Oracle DB.

Comment: Take a look into v$session_longops. Statements running for some time or doing FTS above a certain amount of blocks will be entered there automatically, but unfortunately no guarantee. Columns sofar and totalawork give you a handle for a percentage.

Comment: You might need to get select privileges on that by the DBA.